# How to rename fields to get into json hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, d3.js

I am trying to rename columns once they come out of a database query so I can get them into the correct format for a d3.js graph. This requires the fields to be named source,target,value.

```
def self.including_relationships
    User.select(:follower_id,:followed_id,:value)
      #How do I rename the fields from the line above to the fields below
      obj['links'] << a.slice('source', 'target', 'value')
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
User.select('follower_id, followed_id, value').map(&:attributes)
```

will give you an array of Hash like bellow.

```
[{"follower_id" => 1, "followed_id" => 2, "value" => 1},
{"follower_id" => 1, "followed_id" => 2, "value" => 1},
..........
{"follower_id" => 1, "followed_id" => 2, "value" => 1},]
```

which can be stored as a json casting it.

```
> [{"follower_id" => 1, "followed_id" => 2, "value" => 1}].to_json
=> "[{\"follower_id\":1,\"followed_id\":2,\"value\":1}]"
```

Comment: How does this rename the fields source,target,value   as per the question?

Comment: User.select('follower_id as source, followed_id as target, value').map(&:attributes) will do the stuff.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [ActiveModel::Serializers](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers) or [JBuilder](https://github.com/rails/jbuilder) to customise the JSON output but you should instead consider manipulating the data in javascript.

By doing so you avoid any strong couplings between your server side API and whatever graphing library you use. 
Your API output should not be controlled by how you are displaying the data.

A simplified example using jQuery:

```
var promise = $.getJSON('/users.json');
promise.then(function(data){
  return jQuery.map(data, function(user){
    return {
      target: user.follower_id,
      source: user.followed_id,
      value: user.value
    }
  }).toArray();
});
promise.done(function(data){
  // draw the graph.
});
```